# Extracting Text from a PDF with CID fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, pdfsharp, pdf-extraction

I'm writing a web app that extracts a line at the top of each page in a PDF. The PDFs come from different versions of a product and could go through a number of PDF printers, also in different versions and also different settings.

So far using PDFSharp and iTextSharp I have managed to get it to work for all versions of PDFs. My hang-up is with documents that have CID fonts (Identity-H).

I have written a partial parser to find the font table reference and the text blocks, but converting these to readable text is beating me.

Does anyone have either:
- a parser (like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732265/5169050) that copes with CID fonts; or
- some example code for how to parse a pages resource dictionary to find the pages fonts and get its ToUnicode stream to help finish off this example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4048328/5169050)

We have to use iTextSharp 4.1 to retain the free-to-use license.

Here's my partial parser.

```
public string ExtractTextFromCIDPDFBytes(byte[] input)
{
    if (input == null || input.Length == 0) return "";

    try
    {
        // Holds the final result to be returned
        string resultString = "";
        // Are we in a block of text or not
        bool blnInText = false;
        // Holds each line of text before written to resultString
        string phrase = "";
        // Holds the 4-character hex codes as they are built
        string hexCode = "";
        // Are we in a font reference or not (much like a code block)
        bool blnInFontRef = false;
        // Holds the last font reference and therefore the CMAP table
        // to be used for any text found after it
        string currentFontRef = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = (char)input[i];

            switch (c)
            {
                case '<':
                    {
                        blnInText = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case '>':
                    {
                        resultString = resultString + Environment.NewLine + phrase;
                        phrase = "";
                        blnInText = false;
                        break;
                    }
                case 'T':
                    {
                        switch (((char)input[i + 1]).ToString().ToLower())
                        {
                            case "f":
                                {
                                    // Tf represents the start of a font table reference
                                    blnInFontRef = true;
                                    currentFontRef = "";
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "d":
                                {
                                    // Td represents the end of a font table reference or
                                    // the start of a text block
                                    blnInFontRef = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        if (blnInText)
                        {
                            // We are looking for 4-character blocks of hex characters
                            // These will build up a number which refers to the index
                            // of the glyph in the CMAP table, which will give us the
                            // character
                            hexCode = hexCode + c;
                            if (hexCode.Length == 4)
                            {
                                // TODO - translate code to character
                                char translatedHexCode = c;



                                phrase = phrase + translatedHexCode;
                                // Blank it out ready for the next 4
                                hexCode = "";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (blnInFontRef)
                            {
                                currentFontRef = currentFontRef + c;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        return resultString;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: The trajectory from Page Resource to `/ToUnicode` is described in Adobe's PDF Reference. It's basically the lookup chain `/Page` > `/Resources` > `/Font` > `/ToUnicode` (where most lookups are object references). Parse the ToUnicode mapping and create a new cmap for your font.

Comment: *We have to use iTextSharp 4.1 to retain the free-to-use license.* You should have been at my [JavaOne talk](http://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/ianal-what-developers-should-know-about-ip-and-legal) yesteday. Then you'd understand why your argument is wrong.

Comment: Thank you Jongware, I can now see the structure and the items I think I need. I'm struggling to get an object of anything though and feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

From a PdfPage called page each of the following work in debug and give results, will execute without error, but all will return 'The name 'a' does not exist in the current context'

    PdfDictionary.DictionaryElements a = page.Elements;
    PdfItem b = page.Elements["/Resources"];
    PdfDictionary c = (PdfDictionary)page.Elements["/Resources"];

Bruno, shame I missed it

Comment: If you have a CID font with Identity-H encoding you essentially cannot know what the glyphs represent without a ToUnicode. Sometimes it is possible to parse the underlying embedded font and check if a cmap is present there that can be used for the reverse mapping of glyph IDs into Unicode characters. If both are missing, you are out of luck and cannot find the mapping from the glyph ids into unicode characters (and hence the text meaning).

Comment: I can get the Font and ToUnicode objects now, thanks to the help here. I figured there would be a function in PDFSharp or iTextSharp to convert to readable text once I had a Font object to pass, but I can't find anything to do this for me. Do I really need to parse the text and ToUnicode tables and translate it myself? I mean, I can, but....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took a while but I finally have some code to read plain text from a Identity-H encoded PDF. I post it here to help others, and I know there will be ways to improve upon it. For instance, I haven't touched character mappings (beginbfchar) and my ranges are not actually ranges. I've spent over a week on this already and can't justify the time unless we hit files that work differently. Sorry.

Usage:

```
PdfDocument inputDocument = PDFHelpers.Open(physcialFilePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
foreach (PdfPage page in inputDocument.Pages)
{
    for (Int32 index = 0; index < page.Contents.Elements.Count; index++)
    {
        PdfDictionary.PdfStream stream = page.Contents.Elements.GetDictionary(index).Stream;
        String outputText = new PDFParser().ExtractTextFromPDFBytes(stream.Value).Replace(" ", String.Empty);

        if (outputText == "" || outputText.Replace("\n\r", "") == "")
        {
            // Identity-H encoded file
            string[] hierarchy = new string[] { "/Resources", "/Font", "/F*" };
            List<PdfItem> fonts = PDFHelpers.FindObjects(hierarchy, page, true);
            outputText = PDFHelpers.FromUnicode(stream, fonts);
        }
    }
}
```

And the actual helper class, which I'll post in its entirety, because they are all used in the example, and be because I've found so few complete examples myself when I was trying to solve this issue. The helper uses both PDFSharp and iTextSharp to be able to able to open PDFs pre- and post-1.5, ExtractTextFromPDFBytes to read in a standard PDF, and my FindObjects (to search the document tree and return objects) and FromUnicode that takes encrypted texts and a fonts collection to translate it.

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Content;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace PdfSharp.Pdf.IO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// uses itextsharp 4.1.6 to convert any pdf to 1.4 compatible pdf, called instead of PdfReader.open
    /// </summary>
    static public class PDFHelpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// uses itextsharp 4.1.6 to convert any pdf to 1.4 compatible pdf, called instead of PdfReader.open
        /// </summary>
        static public PdfDocument Open(string PdfPath, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode)
        {
            return Open(PdfPath, null, openmode);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// uses itextsharp 4.1.6 to convert any pdf to 1.4 compatible pdf, called instead of PdfReader.open
        /// </summary>
        static public PdfDocument Open(string PdfPath, string password, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode)
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(PdfPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int len = (int)fileStream.Length;
                // TODO: Setting this byteArray causes the out of memory exception which is why we
                // have the 70mb limit. Solve this and we can increase the file size limit
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                long availableMemory = proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024 / 1024; //Mb of RAM allocated to this process that cannot be shared with other processes
                if (availableMemory < (fileStream.Length / 1024 / 1024))
                {
                    throw new Exception("The available memory " + availableMemory + "Mb is not enough to open, split and save a file of " + fileStream.Length / 1024 / 1024);
                }

                try
                {
                    Byte[] fileArray = new Byte[len];
                    fileStream.Read(fileArray, 0, len);
                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();


                    PdfDocument result = Open(fileArray, openmode);
                    if (result.FullPath == "")
                    {
                        // The file was converted to a v1.4 document and only exists as a document in memory
                        // Save over the original file so other references to the file get the compatible version
                        // TODO: It would be good if we could do this conversion without opening every document another 2 times
                        PdfDocument tempResult = Open(fileArray, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

                        iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont bfR = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\arial.ttf", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                        bfR.Subset = false;

                        tempResult.Save(PdfPath);
                        tempResult.Close();
                        tempResult.Dispose();
                        result = Open(fileArray, openmode);
                    }

                    return result;
                }
                catch (OutOfMemoryException)
                {
                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// uses itextsharp 4.1.6 to convert any pdf to 1.4 compatible pdf, called instead of PdfReader.open
        /// </summary>
        static public PdfDocument Open(byte[] fileArray, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode)
        {
            return Open(new MemoryStream(fileArray), null, openmode);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// uses itextsharp 4.1.6 to convert any pdf to 1.4 compatible pdf, called instead of PdfReader.open
        /// </summary>
        static public PdfDocument Open(byte[] fileArray, string password, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode)
        {
            return Open(new MemoryStream(fileArray), password, openmode);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// uses itextsharp 4.1.6 to convert any pdf to 1.4 compatible pdf, called instead of PdfReader.open
        /// </summary>
        static public PdfDocument Open(MemoryStream sourceStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode)
        {
            return Open(sourceStream, null, openmode);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// uses itextsharp 4.1.6 to convert any pdf to 1.4 compatible pdf, called instead of PdfReader.open
        /// </summary>
        static public PdfDocument Open(MemoryStream sourceStream, string password, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode)
        {
            PdfDocument outDoc = null;
            sourceStream.Position = 0;

            try
            {
                outDoc = (password == null) ?
                      PdfReader.Open(sourceStream, openmode) :
                      PdfReader.Open(sourceStream, password, openmode);

                sourceStream.Position = 0;
                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = (password == null) ?
                      new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourceStream) :
                      new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourceStream, System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
                System.Collections.ArrayList fontList = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.GetDocumentFonts(reader, 1);
            }
            catch (PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReaderException)
            {
                //workaround if pdfsharp doesn't support this pdf
                sourceStream.Position = 0;
                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = (password == null) ?
                      new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourceStream) :
                      new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourceStream, System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password)); 
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper pdfStamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                pdfStamper.Writer.SetPdfVersion(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_4);
                pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                pdfStamper.Close();

                outDoc = PdfReader.Open(outputStream, openmode);
            }

            return outDoc;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses a recurrsive function to step through the PDF document tree to find the specified objects.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objectHierarchy">An array of the names of objects to look for in the tree. Wildcards can be used in element names, e.g., /F*. The order represents 
        /// a top-down hierarchy if followHierarchy is true. 
        /// If a single object is passed in array it should be in the level below startingObject, or followHierarchy set to false to find it anywhere in the tree</param>
        /// <param name="startingObject">A PDF object to parse. This will likely be a document or a page, but could be any lower-level item</param>
        /// <param name="followHierarchy">If true the order of names in the objectHierarchy will be used to search only that branch. If false the whole tree will be parsed for 
        /// any items matching those in objectHierarchy regardless of position</param>
        static public List<PdfItem> FindObjects(string[] objectHierarchy, PdfItem startingObject, bool followHierarchy)
        {
            List<PdfItem> results = new List<PdfItem>();
            FindObjects(objectHierarchy, startingObject, followHierarchy, ref results, 0);
            return results;
        }

        static private void FindObjects(string[] objectHierarchy, PdfItem startingObject, bool followHierarchy, ref List<PdfItem> results, int Level)
        {
            PdfName[] keyNames = ((PdfDictionary)startingObject).Elements.KeyNames;
            foreach (PdfName keyName in keyNames)
            {
                bool matchFound = false;
                if (!followHierarchy)
                {
                    // We need to check all items for a match, not just the top one
                    for (int i = 0; i < objectHierarchy.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (keyName.Value == objectHierarchy[i] ||
                            (objectHierarchy[i].Contains("*") &&
                                (keyName.Value.StartsWith(objectHierarchy[i].Substring(0, objectHierarchy[i].IndexOf("*") - 1)) &&
                                keyName.Value.EndsWith(objectHierarchy[i].Substring(objectHierarchy[i].IndexOf("*") + 1)))))
                        {
                            matchFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Check the item in the hierarchy at this level for a match
                    if (Level < objectHierarchy.Length && (keyName.Value == objectHierarchy[Level] || 
                        (objectHierarchy[Level].Contains("*") &&
                                (keyName.Value.StartsWith(objectHierarchy[Level].Substring(0, objectHierarchy[Level].IndexOf("*") - 1)) &&
                                keyName.Value.EndsWith(objectHierarchy[Level].Substring(objectHierarchy[Level].IndexOf("*") + 1))))))
                    {
                        matchFound = true;
                    }
                }

                if (matchFound)
                {
                    PdfItem item = ((PdfDictionary)startingObject).Elements[keyName];
                    if (item != null && item is PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfReference)
                    {
                        item = ((PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfReference)item).Value;
                    }

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Level " + Level.ToString() + " - " + keyName.ToString() + " matched");

                    if (Level == objectHierarchy.Length - 1)
                    {
                        // We are at the end of the hierarchy, so this is the target
                        results.Add(item);
                    }
                    else if (!followHierarchy)
                    {
                        // We are returning every matching object so add it
                        results.Add(item);
                    }

                    // Call back to this function to search lower levels
                    Level++;
                    FindObjects(objectHierarchy, item, followHierarchy, ref results, Level);
                    Level--;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Level " + Level.ToString() + " - " + keyName.ToString() + " unmatched");
                }
            }
            Level--;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Level " + Level.ToString());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the Font object to translate CID encoded text to readable text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="unreadableText">The text stream that needs to be decoded</param>
        /// <param name="font">A List of PDFItems containing the /Font object containing a /ToUnicode with a CMap</param>
        static public string FromUnicode(PdfDictionary.PdfStream unreadableText, List<PdfItem> PDFFonts)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string[]> fonts = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

            // Get the CMap from each font in the passed array and store them by font name
            for (int font = 0; font < PDFFonts.Count; font++)
            {
                PdfName[] keyNames = ((PdfDictionary)PDFFonts[font]).Elements.KeyNames;
                foreach (PdfName keyName in keyNames)
                {
                    if (keyName.Value == "/ToUnicode") {
                        PdfItem item = ((PdfDictionary)PDFFonts[font]).Elements[keyName];
                        if (item != null && item is PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfReference)
                        {
                            item = ((PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfReference)item).Value;
                        }
                        string FontName = "/F" + font.ToString();
                        string CMap = ((PdfDictionary)item).Stream.ToString();

                        if (CMap.IndexOf("beginbfrange") > 0)
                        {
                            CMap = CMap.Substring(CMap.IndexOf("beginbfrange") + "beginbfrange".Length);

                            if (CMap.IndexOf("endbfrange") > 0)
                            {
                                CMap = CMap.Substring(0, CMap.IndexOf("endbfrange") - 1);

                                string[] CMapArray = CMap.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                fonts.Add(FontName, CMapArray);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Holds the final result to be returned
            string resultString = "";

            // Break the input text into lines
            string[] lines = unreadableText.ToString().Split(new string[] {"\n"} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            // Holds the last font reference and therefore the CMAP table
            // to be used for any text found after it
            string[] currentFontRef = fonts["/F0"];

            // Are we in a block of text or not? They can break across lines so we need an identifier
            bool blnInText = false;

            for (int line = 0; line < lines.Length; line++)
            {
                string thisLine = lines[line].Trim();

                if (thisLine == "q")
                {
                    // I think this denotes the start of a text block, and where we need to reset to the default font
                    currentFontRef = fonts["/F0"];
                }
                else if (thisLine.IndexOf(" Td <") != -1)
                {
                    thisLine = thisLine.Substring(thisLine.IndexOf(" Td <") + 5);
                    blnInText = true;
                }

                if (thisLine.EndsWith("Tf"))
                {
                    // This is a font assignment. Take note of this and use this fonts ToUnicode map when we find text
                    if (fonts.ContainsKey(thisLine.Substring(0, thisLine.IndexOf(" "))))
                    {
                        currentFontRef = fonts[thisLine.Substring(0, thisLine.IndexOf(" "))];
                    }
                } 
                else if (thisLine.EndsWith("> Tj"))
                {
                    thisLine = thisLine.Substring(0, thisLine.IndexOf("> Tj"));
                }

                if(blnInText)
                {
                    // This is a text block
                    try
                    {
                        // Get the section of codes that exist between angled brackets
                        string unicodeStr = thisLine;
                        // Wrap every group of 4 characters in angle brackets
                        // This will directly match the items in the CMap but also allows the next for to avoid double-translating items
                        unicodeStr = "<" + String.Join("><", unicodeStr.SplitInParts(4)) + ">";

                        for (int transform = 0; transform < currentFontRef.Length; transform++)
                        {
                            // Get the last item in the line, which is the unicode value of the glyph
                            string glyph = currentFontRef[transform].Substring(currentFontRef[transform].IndexOf("<"));
                            glyph = glyph.Substring(0, glyph.IndexOf(">") + 1);

                            string counterpart = currentFontRef[transform].Substring(currentFontRef[transform].LastIndexOf("<") + 1);
                            counterpart = counterpart.Substring(0, counterpart.LastIndexOf(">"));

                            // Replace each item that matches with the translated counterpart
                            // Insert a \\u before every 4th character so it's a C# unicode compatible string
                            unicodeStr = unicodeStr.Replace(glyph, "\\u" + counterpart);
                            if (unicodeStr.IndexOf(">") == 0)
                            {
                                // All items have been replaced, so lets get outta here
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        resultString = resultString + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(unicodeStr);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                }

                if (lines[line].Trim().EndsWith("> Tj"))
                {
                    blnInText = false;
                    if (lines[line].Trim().IndexOf(" 0 Td <") == -1)
                    {
                        // The vertical coords have changed, so add a new line
                        resultString = resultString + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultString = resultString + " ";
                    }
                }
            }
            return resultString;
        }

        // Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/
        private static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength)
        {
            if (s == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
            if (partLength <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

            for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
                yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
        }
    }
}

public class PDFParser
{
    /// BT = Beginning of a text object operator
    /// ET = End of a text object operator
    /// Td move to the start of next line
    ///  5 Ts = superscript
    /// -5 Ts = subscript

    #region Fields

    #region _numberOfCharsToKeep
    /// <summary>
    /// The number of characters to keep, when extracting text.
    /// </summary>
    private static int _numberOfCharsToKeep = 15;
    #endregion

    #endregion



    #region ExtractTextFromPDFBytes
    /// <summary>
    /// This method processes an uncompressed Adobe (text) object
    /// and extracts text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">uncompressed</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ExtractTextFromPDFBytes(byte[] input)
    {
        if (input == null || input.Length == 0) return "";

        try
        {
            string resultString = "";

            // Flag showing if we are we currently inside a text object
            bool inTextObject = false;

            // Flag showing if the next character is literal
            // e.g. '\\' to get a '\' character or '\(' to get '('
            bool nextLiteral = false;

            // () Bracket nesting level. Text appears inside ()
            int bracketDepth = 0;

            // Keep previous chars to get extract numbers etc.:
            char[] previousCharacters = new char[_numberOfCharsToKeep];
            for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfCharsToKeep; j++) previousCharacters[j] = ' ';


            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = (char)input[i];

                if (inTextObject)
                {
                    // Position the text
                    if (bracketDepth == 0)
                    {
                        if (CheckToken(new string[] { "TD", "Td" }, previousCharacters))
                        {
                            resultString += "\n\r";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (CheckToken(new string[] { "'", "T*", "\"" }, previousCharacters))
                            {
                                resultString += "\n";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (CheckToken(new string[] { "Tj" }, previousCharacters))
                                {
                                    resultString += " ";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // End of a text object, also go to a new line.
                    if (bracketDepth == 0 &&
                        CheckToken(new string[] { "ET" }, previousCharacters))
                    {

                        inTextObject = false;
                        resultString += " ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Start outputting text
                        if ((c == '(') && (bracketDepth == 0) && (!nextLiteral))
                        {
                            bracketDepth = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Stop outputting text
                            if ((c == ')') && (bracketDepth == 1) && (!nextLiteral))
                            {
                                bracketDepth = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Just a normal text character:
                                if (bracketDepth == 1)
                                {
                                    // Only print out next character no matter what.
                                    // Do not interpret.
                                    if (c == '\\' && !nextLiteral)
                                    {
                                        nextLiteral = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (((c >= ' ') && (c <= '~')) ||
                                            ((c >= 128) && (c < 255)))
                                        {
                                            resultString += c.ToString();
                                        }

                                        nextLiteral = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Store the recent characters for
                // when we have to go back for a checking
                for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfCharsToKeep - 1; j++)
                {
                    previousCharacters[j] = previousCharacters[j + 1];
                }
                previousCharacters[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] = c;

                // Start of a text object
                if (!inTextObject && CheckToken(new string[] { "BT" }, previousCharacters))
                {
                    inTextObject = true;
                }
            }
            return resultString;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CheckToken
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a certain 2 character token just came along (e.g. BT)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="search">the searched token</param>
    /// <param name="recent">the recent character array</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CheckToken(string[] tokens, char[] recent)
    {
        foreach (string token in tokens)
        {
            if (token.Length > 1)
            {
                if ((recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 3] == token[0]) &&
                    (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 2] == token[1]) &&
                    ((recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] == ' ') ||
                    (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] == 0x0d) ||
                    (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] == 0x0a)) &&
                    ((recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 4] == ' ') ||
                    (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 4] == 0x0d) ||
                    (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 4] == 0x0a))
                    )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Thank you to all those who provided help and snippets that allowed me to finally pull a working solution together

Comment: Why do you only consider fonts whose name starts with an **F**? `string[] hierarchy = new string[] { "/Resources", "/Font", "/F*" };`

Comment: Under the /Font object is a collection of fonts with incremental zero-based names, e.g., /F0, /F1, /F2.

So /F* represents anything that starts with "/F". It doesn't relate to the font name. As far as I'm aware fonts aren't stored as anything else. But if they were you could tweak the search parameters

Comment: *Under the /Font object is a collection of fonts with incremental zero-based names, e.g., /F0, /F1, /F2* - these names **F0**, **F1**, ... are not required, they can also be named **Helv**, **Arial**, **Bobo**, whatever.

Comment: Interesting. I've only been working with a small set of files produced by a different versions of one particular system, so hadn't come across that. As it's a parameter you could still change it to Helv, Arial, Bobo, etc. It would need tweaking to accept "*" as the parameter though.

Comment: I looked at your code some more and it does indeed look like you derived the program logic more from a number of similar sample documents than from the pdf specification. I think you are in for some surprises as soon as you apply your code to pdfs generated by other than the *one particular system* you talk about. ;)

Comment: haha Thanks for taking the time. I know it's a _just about_ system that's a product of learning as I go. I hope it will be a starting point for someone, maybe myself. Such is a coders life. Every time you look back at your code you want to rewrite it.